WalletMultiButton stucked on connecting
I have the following problem.
I have launched a vite project on my local network, so I can acces it from different computers.
The endPoint of the ConnectionProvider is get by using clusterApiUrl("devnet")
The phantom wallet on each computer on the network is setted to devnet.
The problem is when I want to connect the wallet from other computers on the network it does not work.
